# Access 16 bit array with 64 bit pointers in unsafe mode

Tags: c#, arrays, pointers, unsafe

Here is my code:

```
              long max = pcmU16.Length;
              long index = 0;

              fixed (ushort* srcFix = pcmU16)
              {
                    ushort* src = srcFix;

                    next:

                    *src = 32768;
                    src++;
                    index++;

                    if (index != max)
                    {
                          goto next;
                    }
              }
```

Like you see, it is writing 2 bytes at once. How to use ulong type and write 8 bytes at once? pcmU16 is ushort[] array.

Comment: It works without (void*). I discovered it 5 minutes ago. Before I was not using * at casting, that was my problem. Make an answer so I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just coerce it:

```
ulong* src = (ulong*)srcFix;
```

Things to watch, though:

- your `max` needs to be divided by 4, else you're going out of range
- you need to handle any stray values - for example, say you have 10 `ushort` values (`max` was 10 initially); that is 2 sets of `ulong` (4 each), and a final 2 `ushort`; the usual divisor/remainder stuff

As a final note, you *might* find the index syntax more convenient, i.e.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < max ; i++) {
    src[i] = ...
}
```